# regression - Considering all interactions between variables. PLS, Regression, or neither?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, pca, feature-selection, partial-least-squares

I am dealing with a dataset where `p>>N` and I have executed several different techniques to understand what are the most important features. These include, lasso regression, random forests, adaptive boosting forests, and mixed selection. I have no way of verifying these feature are better outside of the subspace only containing them outperforms (in terms of ROC) my full feature space.

I am considering building a regression with every single interaction between all 1000 variables I am dealing with to gain significance in which interactions are most important. Is there a better way of going about this? This feels very brute force, but also feels very thorough.

I found a very helpful [link](http://faculty.chicagobooth.edu/richard.hahn/teaching/FormulaNotation.pdf) at executing this. This equips me with the `formula()` syntax to get at every interaction between a single variable. Is there a better way than looping through my entire dataset and manufacturing a formula string that concatenates every variable separated by a `*` to get all of the interactions?

Is this really the best way? I was considering looking at covariances and correlations, but I think the regression gets at the spirit of both in addition to a p-value for significance in a relationship to the response existing.

Does PLS account for this any better? Does PCA give us sufficient information to know how many significant features exist?

Comment: Do you really need to select features? There exists kernel methods (for Rıdge and PLS regressıon) that deals with quadratic and interaction terms in an efficient manner.

Comment: Is your question about constructing a data set that consists of the actual variables and their interactions, then evaluating them to see which ones are important?

Comment: I wasn't aware kernel methods included interaction terms. Basically, what is the best way of finding the most important interactions in my 1000 variables? Is a brute force linear regression the best way?

Comment: I am having trouble finding where ridge or pls actually account for interactions `between` variables, not just whether they are independently affecting of the response. Could you point me to some documentation?